# Azure Synapse. Hash distributed table on a column with unique values

Tags: azure, distribution, azure-synapse

I can't really see the difference between a round robin distribution an a hash distribution on a column with completely unique and distinct values. I mean, they would both have an even distribution but with no grouped values of the same category, right? Is it that the hash distribution remembers the hash key and stored position somewhere, so it is more performant?

Answer (score 2):

Hash-distributed tables improve query performance on large fact tables, Round-robin tables are useful for improving loading speed. Since identical values always hash to the same distribution, SQL Analytics has built-in knowledge of the row locations. In dedicated SQL pool this knowledge is used to minimize data movement during queries, which improves query performance.

In a round-robin distributed table, rows are distributed evenly across all distributions. But the assignment of rows to distributions is random. Unlike hash-distributed tables, rows with equal values are not guaranteed to be assigned to the same distribution.

As a result, the system sometimes needs to invoke a data movement operation to better organize your data before it can resolve a query. This extra step can slow down your queries.